Can't switch back to desktop layout on embedded PowerBI report
I have an embedded PowerBI report on a web page and I am using the PowerBI JavaScript API to switch to mobile layout when the window width is less than 640px. Switching to mobile layout works but then when I try to switch back to the default desktop layout it just stays in the mobile layout.
I am switching to the mobile view using the following code:
var newSettings = {
    layoutType: models.LayoutType.MobilePortrait
};
report.updateSettings(newSettings);

This part works perfectly. But then when I try to switch back to the default/desktop layout it does not work. I tried to use either
var newSettings = {
    layoutType: models.LayoutType.Master
};
report.updateSettings(newSettings);

or
var newSettings = {
    layoutType: models.LayoutType.Custom
};
report.updateSettings(newSettings);

Since these are listed in the models.LayoutType property. But it just stays in the mobile layout. I'm not getting any error messages either.

Can you please provide the complete code snippet as to how you are checking the condition to switch to mobile layout when the window width is less than 640px?
Also, is your web page a react-based or angular-based web page application?

For the desktop you should use the DisplayOption.FitToPage is used to scale the report to fit the page.
const desktopSettings = {
    layoutType: models.LayoutType.Custom,
    customLayout: {
        displayOption: models.DisplayOption.FitToPage
    }
};
report.updateSettings(desktopSettings);


This scales the mobile view to fit the iframe but it does not change the layout to the default/desktop layout.
